# Summation of list using single loop

Tags: java

How to sum the given array of elements in array which elements has present in the list is only once. If the element present the list twice or more it not participate in summation ..

Ex..

```
A[ ]={4,2,3,1,2,3,3};
Sum=4+1=5;
```

Because ..2 and 3 are more than once in the list.
Here the problem we must use only one loop .do not use inner loop also .
How to solve that problem in single loop..

Comment: What language are you actually using?

Comment: I'm using java .

Comment: When I see answers with Map I can answer like this: use IntStream.of(A).distinct().sum();. Of course Java hides lots of algorithms inside.

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets Wouldn't that include the non-unique numbers once though?

Comment: Yes, but I see in question "we must use only one loop", that mean that question about algorithms, not about using of Java language itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Map` for collect used elements and `boolean` marker for undo operation.

```
public static int sumUniqueElements(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int val : arr) {
        if (map.containsKey(val)) {
            if (map.get(val) == Boolean.TRUE) {
                sum -= val;
                map.put(val, Boolean.FALSE);
            }
        } else {
            sum += val;
            map.put(val, Boolean.TRUE);
        }
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: No offense but you should have kept this to yourself. Craig gave him all the needed directives that would make him think about a solution and you just messed it up.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not going to give you a direct answer, but I'll propose some things for you to think about which should help you.

- You can easily keep an efficient O(1) complexity collection of numbers you *have seen*. What would that be?
- The difficulty is that when you first "see" a number, you have no idea if it will be repeated later. So you're kind of forced to *add it in* immediately. (I.e. optimistically)
- If you see the number again: Can you think of any way to "undo" the previous time you *added it in*?
- Don't forget that when you see it a third or more time, there's no need to "undo" again.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with java streams to sum up only single elements :

```
System.out.println(
         Stream.of(4, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 3)
         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(k->k, Collectors.counting()))
         .entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
         .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
         .sum());
```

Outputs : 5

Comment: While this code looks like it doesn't use any loops, under the hood, it uses 2.